# How are group ids assigned?

Tags: groups, osx-lion, mac-osx

I want to create a `developers` group on my OS-X system.  I'm executing:

```
sudo dscl . -create /groups/developers
sudo dscl . -append /groups/developers passwd 'blah'
```

My understanding from reading various sources is that I should assign an id to the group with

```
sudo dscl . -append /groups/developers gid xxx
```

where xxx is the desired id.  My question is, what is an appropriate value for *xxx*?  Is there a convention?  Are there any BAD choices?  Do I have to worry that something else will want to use the same group id?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OS X conventionally uses different ID ranges for different types of accounts.  Here's the current layout as I understand it:

up to 100: Reserved for static system-defined (built in) groups
101 - 199: Used by the OS for dynamically-created groups (e.g. share point access groups)
200 - ?: More static system groups (apparently 100 wasn't enough)
400 - 500: More dynamic system groups
501 and up: Local admin-created groups
1024 and up: Domain-based admin-created groups

Since you're creating a local group, I'd look for the first available ID number above 500.

Answer (score 2):

One thing you have to take care when choosing a group id is that the id is not already used by another group. In order to list the existing group ids in numerical order you can do:

```
dscl . -list /groups PrimaryGroupID | awk '{print $2}' | sort -n
```